# app crashes in simulator not on device for converting date format

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, fatal-error

On Converting "2019-04-25 15:31:22" into  date format "MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm", app crashes in simulator but works fine on device.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
func convertToString (dateString: String, formatIn : String, formatOut : String) -> String {
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.timeZone = (NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "IST")! as TimeZone)
    dateFormater.dateFormat = formatIn
    let date = dateFormater.date(from: dateString)
    dateFormater.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
    dateFormater.dateFormat = formatOut
    let timeStr = dateFormater.string(from: date!)
    return timeStr
}
```

Printing description of timeStr:

> expression produced error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.
>   The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Want to understand `convertToString` is properly code.

One service output response in formate of `"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"` & another
services response date formate is `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"`

```
    let convertedFormat =  convertToString(dateString: lastTime, 
formatIn: "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", formatOut: "MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm")

let convertedDate =  convertToString(dateString: headline.publishedAt!, formatIn: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", formatOut: "MMMM dd yyyy, hh:mm")
cell.lbl_NewsDate?.text = convertedDate
```

I want to use common utility converter function to show resultant time in **"MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm"** example **Apr 26 2019, 23:32**

resultant time need to show based on "Indian Standard Time".

Comment: make sure to set your date formatter locale to `"en_US_POSIX"`. Btw Are you sure that date string it is not UTC time?

Comment: You do 2 forced unwraps...which is nil, `date` or the "IST" time zone?  (Also, what is your `formatIn`?)

Comment: Unrelated but don't use `NSTimeZone`, Create using `TimeZone` directly. No need for the cast when created correctly.

Comment: Please write example of code, how you execute convertToString.

Comment: @PhillipMills I updated my question,  I assume IST is time zone, Indian Standard Time.

Comment: Your input format uses `hh`, which is 12-hour time.  Since you're giviing it a 24-hour time as input ("15:..."), you need `HH` in the input format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, that you use incorrect date format "MMM dd yyyy, hh:mm" in:

```
formatIn: String, formatOut: String
```

Hours is "HH", but not "hh".

Comment: Both `HH` and `hh` are hours. One is for 24-hour format and the other is for 12-hour format.

Comment: I think you're really close to the right answer.  The problem is that the **input** format is hh with a time specified as "15:31:22".

Comment: @PhillipMills  it’s true hh vs HH Makes difference lot,  but why not crashes in iPhone device.

Comment: @kiran Maybe you gave it a different input string?  Maybe you found a bug in the device library?  I don't know but HH **should** work on both.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
func convertToString(dateString: String, formatIn: String, formatOut: String) -> String {
    let dateFormater = DateFormatter()
    dateFormater.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    dateFormater.dateFormat = formatIn
    let date = dateFormater.date(from: dateString)
    dateFormater.timeZone = NSTimeZone.system
    dateFormater.dateFormat = formatOut
    let timeStr = dateFormater.string(from: date ?? Date())
    return timeStr
}
```

And check the data in variables: dateString, formatIn, formatOut are they have correct data